# Javascript remove variable value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My create.js.erb:

```
var flashSuccess = "<%=flash[:add_comment_success]%>";
if (flashSuccess){
  $("#flash_messages").html("<div class='messages_notify'><div id='message-add_comment_success'><p class='message_content'></p></div></div>");
noty_ajax();
flashSuccess = undefined
}



var flashError = "<%=flash[:add_comment_error]%>";
if (flashError){
  $("#flash_messages").html("<div class='messages_notify'><div id='message-add_comment_error'><p class='message_content'></p></div></div>");
noty_ajax();
flashError = undefined
}
```

My app.js file:

```
function noty_ajax(){
$(".messages_notify #message-add_comment_success" ).each( function(){
        generate('success', 'Coment added.');
    }).remove();

    $( ".messages_notify #message-add_comment_error" ).each( function(){
        generate('error', 'Comment Error');
    }).remove();
}
```

And what is a problem. When i click button that generate error message and then click a button that generate success message - when it generate success message it also generate error message - so there are two messages. I try to remove as you can see "flashError" and "flasSuccess" after executed but it doesnt change anything. Can you see where this second messages is generated and what i can do to remove it?

ANSWER

flashError and flashSuccess was always true, and dont know why, on second request two of them wasnt empty. I resolve this with generating two differents js files, rendered from controller :

```
if @comment.save
 return respond_to do |format|

    flash[:add_comment_success] = "success"
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    format.js {render 'comments/success'}   /// and error.js.erb for error message
  end
else
     return respond_to do |format|

    flash[:add_comment_error] = "error"
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    format.js {render 'comments/error'}   /// and error.js.erb for error message
  end
end
```

Now there is no two variable in generated js so it works.

Comment: Open console and see what this does `Boolean('random string value')` indeed, it's _true_ every time...

Comment: Your flashError or flashSuccess are string so they always true, unless  string is empty - `!!''` is `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `flashSuccess` and `flashError` are not boolean values and the if conditions in your create.js will always be true.
Hence both the messages will be displayed everytime.

Comment: Thanks. I think i resolve it with rendering two different files in controller - post edited.